# PHP: utf-8 encode, htmlentities giving weird results

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I'm trying to get data from a POST form. When the user inputs `"habláis"`, it shows up in view source as just `"habláis"`. I want to convert this to `"habl&aacute;is"` for purposes of string comparison, but both `utf8_encode()` and `htmlentities()` are outputting `habl&Atilde;&iexcl;is`, and `htmlspecialchars()` does nothing. I would use `str_replace` but it won't recognize the á when it searches the string.

I'm using a charset of utf-8 consistently across pages. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but are you calling [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) with the UTF-8 parameter?  I ask because that's not its default:

> Like htmlspecialchars(), it takes an
>   optional third argument charset which
>   defines character set used in
>   conversion. Presently, the ISO-8859-1
>   character set is used as the default.

So you might want to try calling your function like this:

```
$output = htmlentities($input, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably not specifying UTF-8 as the character set for the [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) operation.